# PHP URL Default Variable

Tags: php, variables

I've got a script that uses a url parameter to hit a service that returns a set of data. I would like however to add "default" values to the two variables that I have set.

reporting/interface/charts/services/ticketsopenedclosed.php?startDate=&endDate=",

My initial thought was to use an if statement but I'm not sure how to use logic on the variable such as if $startdate = null ... default value.

Perhaps there is a better way to do this other than an if statement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many frameworks use helper functions to cope with this, for example you could use something like:

```
function getRequest($key, $default=null) {
    // Using $_REQUEST for brevity, up to you if you want to use $_GET or $_POST
    if(!isset($_REQUEST)) {
        return $default;
    }
    return $_REQUEST[$key];
}
```

This way, you can always call the following, and know you'll always get something useful:

```
 $start_date = getRequest('startDate', date('c'));
```

You should ideally wrap this into a class.